Languages with very small "modal inventories"
I'm interested in frameworks for describing how languages encode mood. For example, I'm curious whether something similar to a case hierarchy or color hierarchy exists for moods. Or if there are proposed features like identity of deontic and epistemic modality for quickly describing the modal system of a given language.
Those questions are way too broad and vague, so instead I want to focus on languages with especially simple modal inventories, since they are extreme in some way.

I speak English natively and have studied French and Standard Mandarin.
Subjectively, the modal system of French seems very similar to English, although some things that English expresses periphrastically I will go, I would go are expressed morphologically in French j'irai, j'irais.
The modal system of Standard Mandarin, however, feels very, very different. 应该 yīnggāi seems to basically be equivalent to English should (in both its deontic and non-deontic senses), but 会 huì, 要 yào, 想 xiǎng do not appear to have straightforward English equivalents. Of the possible modal meanings one might wish to attach to a proposition, Mandarin and English use different strategies to encode them and carve up the semantic space differently. Neither appears to be simpler or more complex than the other.
This leads me to the question of whether there are any languages with uncontroversially simple modal inventories, for example one general purpose irrealis morpheme or even no explicit encoding of modal information at all.

What in the world is that transcription system? Yīnggāi, huì and xiǎng would be standard Pinyin.

@JanusBahsJacquet it’s Gwoyeu Romatzyh 国语罗马字.

Seang isn’t; that should be sheang. Also why? GR is the most unnecessarily complicated and least logical of all the schemes available …

@JanusBahsJacquet Y'know, you make a good point. I like the idea of using extra letters to mark tones and GR is the most common of these systems (the others are even more obscure), but I still make mistakes with GR constantly. Maybe it's time to give up.

What is the modal system of French?

@Lambie https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(grammaire)

@jlliagre We don't say modal system in English. We say the mood of a verb. As in subjunctive, for example.  My point is to communicate effectively with the OP, not see French stuff I already know.

@Lambie That sounds like useless nitpicking. The OP is a native speaker and not the first one to use modal system.  See for example William Divers who looked to know what he was speaking about.

@Lambie to add to the above comment for jlliagre, the "modal system" is perfectly reasonably intelligible as the "system of moods" as the term "modal" is frequently used when discussing grammatical mood in English in the sense of "of moods". It's clearly parallel to "tense system"/"system of tenses" & "aspectual system"/"system of aspects" and in both cases the former is more commonly used

The French wikipedia link: Le mode (du latin modus, « manière ») est un trait grammatical qui dénote la manière dont le verbe exprime le fait, qu'il soit état ou action (la terminologie linguistique emploie le terme procès). Le plus souvent associé au verbe, ce trait ne lui est cependant pas exclusif. Les modes verbaux représentent la manière dont l'action exprimée par le verbe est conçue et présentée..

The English link (top right of the page) to the French x \In linguistics, grammatical mood is a grammatical feature of verbs, used for signaling modality.[1][2]: 181 [3] That is, it is the use of verbal inflections that allow speakers to express their attitude toward what they are saying (for example, a statement of fact, of desire, of command, etc.). The term is also used more broadly to describe the syntactic expression of modality – that is, the use of verb phrases that do not involve inflection of the verb itself.

@Lambie French has four morphological moods: the indicative, the imperative, the conditional, and the subjunctive. It also has pouvoir which corresponds to English can and may and devoir which corresponds to must and should. The point I was trying to make is that English and French are similar when it comes to modal constructions, the biggest difference I can see being that the French conditional mood is encoded using inflection rather than an auxiliary verb, and possibly the lack of an impersonal verb of necessity like falloir in English.

From what I can gather, languages have a wide variety of constructions for signalling modal information and defining what counts as modal information using semantic criteria exclusively is controversial. For example, does adding probably to an English sentence change the modal content?
That's why I'm trying to narrow my question to just asking for an example of a language with a very simple modal system.

OK, I think I now get your point. Both French and English have modal verbs (verbes modaux AKA auxiliaires de modalité). This site explains these simply in French, which are basically the verbs pouvoir, devoir, vouloir + an infinitive. They are called "auxiliaires": https://stewdy.com/soutien-scolaire/francais/comment-et-pourquoi-utiliser-les-verbes-modaux-en-francais/ In that sense, they are similar to English modal verbs construction-wise: modal (can, should, must etc.) + infinitive.  Except in French, conjugated. Je dois partir. I must leave. verb mood is a separate topic.
